# Hyperconverged Hyper-V using three servers

Tags: hyper-v

Currently I have two independent servers running Hyper-V.
I`m looking for ways to add more redundancy and bought a third server that equals the capacity of server 1 and 2.

I would like the third server to be the failover node. In case server 1 , 2 or both go down, I want it to resume the VM on server 3.

I dug into Storage Spaces Direct (S2D) and Nutanix, but can not find relevant information regarding my desired setup.

Is it even possible? If so, I would like to have some pointers please :)

Comment: It is possible, it is what S2D does. Which is Windows Server 2016. Not even in beta.

Comment: From what Microsoft publishes S2D needs at least *FOUR* servers and cannot use only three. This may change in future as nothing is in stone but not yet.

Comment: There is no need for 3rd server if you would stick with some virtual SAN solution. You can build 2 node HA cluster with StarWind Virtual SAN or HP VSA for example. BTW StarWind performs great with Storage Spaces from what I have tested personally. StarWind: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/download-starwind-products HP VSA: http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/storage-software/product-detail.html?oid=5306917

Comment: HP VSA needs an additional quorum and is limited by 50TB, furthermore their new licensing sucks (time-bombing customers). Starwind is perpetual which is awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read above and in another thread bumped around this one.

So we got these options now [UPDATED]:

1) **Storage Spaces Direct**. Datacenter-only, can't be used with a free Hyper-V Server.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-direct-overview

2) **StarWind Virtual SAN**. Has unlimited free version being OK for production you can use with Hyper-V Server.

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san

3) **HPE VSA**. Has 1TB free version, time-bombed, OK for production use.

https://www.hpe.com/emea_europe/en/storage/storevirtual.html

**Nutanix** isn't really an option because their community edition (CE) is KVM bound, you can't use it with either Hyper-V or VMware hypervisors.